# jQuery fade not working after media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a logo on my website that fades in. If you get below a certain screen size the following media query changes this image with css. If the media query is not triggered the fade works perfectly fine. When it is the fade just doesn't happen.

**HTML**

```
<span class="col-md-6" id="header">
    <a href="/">
        <img src="/share/images/design/logo/desktop.png" title="Home"/>
    <a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
@media(max-width: 991px)
{ 
    #header img 
    {
        content: url('/share/images/design/logo/mobile.png');

        display: block;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    $("#header").hide();
    $("#header").fadeIn(750);
```

I tried executing the code in the console and that seemed to work. Although on a normal refresh it doesn't seem to be working. How would you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your main issue is you're trying to change the image path of your logo using `content:` which 1. only works with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and 2. will not replace an image path of an `img`.

I'm assuming you want to keep the `img` tags and not use a `background-image` so I think the best thing to do is to add both images to the page with different `class` names and use the media queries to show and hide them:

```
<img src="http://www.dalthow.com/share/images/design/logo/desktop.png" title="Home"  class="desktop">
<img src="http://www.dalthow.com/share/images/design/logo/mobile.png" title="Home" class="mobile">
```

Next change your CSS to `display:none` on the one you don't want to show and `opacity:0` on the one you do want to show:

```
#header .mobile{
   display: none;
}

#header .desktop{
   display: block; //add to override media query if user is resizing browser
   opacity: 0;
}

@media(max-width: 991px){ 

    #header .desktop{
        display: none;
    }

    #header .mobile{
      display: block; //add to override media query if user is resizing browser
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to use a check window size check with jQuery and you can just call:

```
$("#header img").animate({"opacity": "1"},750); //same effect as fadeIn
```

Don't forget to remove `$("#header").hide();` This is no longer needed

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh9vh2ps/1/)

Comment: But... double download  Why not display the small image by default and then use a min-width media query to only override that image with the larger one on larger devices?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use callbacks

example:

```
$("#menu").slideToggle(750, function () {
    $("#header").fadeIn(750);
});
```

Comment: which ever effect you want to complete first you need to call that and then other effect follows

Comment: This would only make it so the fade happens after the slide toggle, with that it still doesn't fade in if you re-size your screen to have to mobile logo.

Comment: for that you to handle fade effect on window resize event